# How to apply SLDS on Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, slds

I downloaded SLDS and saved as a static resource. Then I applied the style on Visualforce page, but it's not working.
How can I apply SLDS on Visualforce Page?

Lightning Design System Static Resource
https://lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/

I tried tag '<apex:slds /> ', but it's not working in community page. I want to apply slds on Visuforce Page in community page.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
<head>    
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds2_12_2, 'styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}"/>
</head>
<div class="slds">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">SLDS On Visualforce page</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
            <apex:commandLink value="">
                <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--brand">Cancel</button>
            </apex:commandLink>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

I tried the code below, but there is the differences between the normal Vf page and the enbeded Vf page in community.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
<html>
    <body>
        <apex:slds />
        <apex:form id="form" styleClass="slds-scope">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">SLDS On Visualforce page</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                <apex:commandLink value="Cancel" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand"></apex:commandLink>
            </div>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Normal Vf page (not community)
[image]

enbeded Vf page in community
[image]

Comment: I tried  <apex:slds />, but it's not working on community page.

Comment: To confirm, you dropped an Visualforce component into your Lightning Community page or are you using an older Site?

Comment: I dropped an Visualforce page into my Lightning Community page.

Comment: Did you add the `slds-scope` class to your page over content you want to style?

Comment: check the example I added to my answer

Answer (score 3):

Downloading the CSS and re-uploading it as a static resource is unnecessary. You can use the SLDS stylesheets by [adding the `<apex:slds />` tag to your Visualforce page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_slds.htm). [This is documented on the SLDS site under Visualforce](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/visualforce/), the download is offered if you want to use the CSS *outside* of Salesforce.

You can also scope where you want the SLDS styles to be applied.

```html
<apex:page standardController="Account" applyBodyTag="false">
    <apex:slds /> 
 
    <!-- any Visualforce component should be outside SLDS scoping element -->
    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.OwnerId}" /> 
 
    <div class="slds-scope">
    <!-- SLDS markup here -->
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

**Additionally,** make sure you're using the appropriate markup for the SLDS class names. Many of the classes that use double hyphens (`--`) have been deprecated.

## EDIT

This example works in a Community Visualforce component.

```html
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <html>
        <body>
            <apex:slds />
            <apex:form id="form" styleClass="slds-scope">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">SLDS On Visualforce page</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Cancel" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand"></apex:commandLink>
                </div>
            </apex:form>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The tag '<apex:slds />' is working normal Visualforce page but, it's not working in community.

Comment: The VF page will render in an iframe, there should be no differences between what you see by navigating to the page directly (at /apex/MyPage) vs what you see when you drag and drop the Visualforce page into the Community as a component. Can you share the code that you're currently using so we can help troubleshoot it?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried the code you showed.(I updated my question and add the images) It's working if it's not in community, but it's not working in community.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue could be based on what you've shared. I would post a new question specific to the new issue you're having i.e. lightning stylesheets are not applied to a Visualforce page rendered in a Lightning Community